# Django Rest Framework não filtra após redefinir queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Minha url será algo como: .../?search=modal.

Quero substituir o "modal" por vazio "" para que limpe o filtro e retorne todos os registros.

**Views.py**

```
class AnexoExamesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

search_fields = ['descr']
filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
queryset = AnexoExames.objects.all()
serializer_class = AnexoExamesSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = AnexoExames.objects.all()
    search_descr = self.request.query_params.get('search',None)
    print(search_descr)
    if search_descr=='modal':            
        queryset = AnexoExames.objects.filter(descr='')                
    return queryset
```

Desta forma ele está retornando zero resultados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = self.queryset
    search_descr = self.request.query_params.get('search', None)

    if search_descr=='modal':            
        qs = qs.filter(descr='')                
    return qs
```